# Web.xml is not getting included in War using mvn plugin

Tags: java, maven, plugins, dependency-management

I am trying to include web.xml in war.

Here is how my `pom.xml` looks like, I have added `maven-resources-plugin` and `maven-war-plugin` to pom

```pom
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>copy-web.xml</id>
      <phase>process-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/war/WEB-INF</outputDirectory>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
              <include>web.xml</include>
            </includes>
          </resource>
        </resources>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <webXml>${basedir}/war/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
  </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3</version>
  <configuration>
    <filesets>
      <fileset>
        <directory>tomcat</directory>
      </fileset>
      <fileset>
        <directory>war/WEB-INF/classes</directory>
      </fileset>
      <fileset>
        <directory>war/WEB-INF/lib</directory>
      </fileset>
    </filesets>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But when I extract war here is what I get

```
/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/XProject/WEB-INF
/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/XProject/WEB-INF/classes
/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/XProject/WEB-INF/lib
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: can you please share the entire pom.xml

Comment: Why do you need to filter web.xml ?

Comment: @SaurabhJhunjhunwala - This is more or less all I have in pom , that is of use in this regard, rest of the pom include dependencies and other plugins.

Comment: @khmarbaise - no specific use, I was just experimenting few changes.

Comment: did you add **<packaging>war</packaging>** in your pom.xml

Comment: @SaurabhJhunjhunwala - yes its included.

Answer (score 2):

I have used multiple time maven-war-plugin. Here is the code snippet. This will include the web.xml if web.xml is present in your folder structure else ignore.

The problem which I think from your code snippet, may be issue with relative path for the web.xml. Use the below maven-war-plugin to resolve your issue

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Comment: still no luck with that.

Comment: did u check the relative path of web.xml ? and remove maven-resources-plugin from your pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

Add the warsourcedirectory tag.

```
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem while having the web.xml in the default path

```
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

but wasn't included in the .war.

Following @sitakant suggestion I removed the maven-resources-plugin from the pom.xml and web.xml is now included in the .war without further configurations.